# Imposing an arbitrary constraint on a overparametrized ANOVA model

Tags: regression, anova, linear-model, identifiability

Casella & Berger 2nd ed. stated that $\tag{11.2.2}Y_{ij}=\mu+\tau_i+\epsilon_{ij},\quad i=1,\cdots,k,\quad j=1,\cdots,n_i$
is an overparameterized model such that a constraint on $\tau_i$ should be added such as $\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_i=0$ to make the model identifiable.

I would like to know if an arbitrary constraint such as a linear constraint in $\tau_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^kc_i\tau_i=0$ could be imposed. If yes, how do I **actually impose it**? Or in other words, what should I do to extract the calculate the values of $\tau_i$ given a constraint. An example and/or relevant R functions would be great!